# How Can I check if $property exist in a list @properties in msbuild

Tags: c#, msbuild

I have a list of properties that return some list of strings value v1;v2;V3. I have property that contain a string value and I need to check if this value contain in the list of string, if the value exist return an error

```
<Error Condition="@(ListOfValues)== $(property)" Text="This Value already exists!"/>
```

it doesn't seem it is working

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it myself

```
<Error Condition="%(ListOfValues.Identity)== $(property)" Text="This Value already exists!"/>
```